# How to visualize data after performing OneHotEncoding and normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-cleaning, normalization, binary-classification

I have a dataset and on that, I have performed OneHotEncoding and Standardization using standard scalar, Now that I have preprocessed data I have to visualize it, but on converting it to pandas dataframe it is showing error. What is the way to visualize preprocessed data?

steps that I have taken

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

categorical_features = [column names which are categorical in nature]

numerical_features = [column names which are numerical in nature]

one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
scaler = StandardScaler()

tranformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot", one_hot, categorial_features),("standard_scaler", scaler, numerical_features)], remainder = "passthrough")

transformed_X = tranformer.fit_transform(X)
```

Now, how to view this `transformed_X` in a tabular manner that we see using the `.head()` function of pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```py
col_names = list(tranformer.named_transformers_['one_hot'].get_feature_names())+numerical_features

df1 = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(transformed_X)
df1.columns = col_names
df1.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

After applying one-hot encoding and standardization, the `transformed_X` data is no longer a pandas DataFrame, but a **numpy ndarray**. To convert it back to a pandas `DataFrame`, you can use the `pd.DataFrame()` function as follows:

```
transformed_X_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed_X, columns=tranformer.get_feature_names())
```

This will give you a DataFrame with the same number of rows as the original dataset `X`, but with **transformed columns**. You can then use the `.head()` function to view the first few rows of this DataFrame:

```
transformed_X_df.head()
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `pandas.concat()` function to concatenate the **transformed data** with the original data and create a new DataFrame with all the columns:

```
X_df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=[categorical_features + numerical_features])
transformed_X_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed_X, columns=tranformer.get_feature_names())
final_df = pd.concat([X_df, transformed_X_df], axis=1)
final_df.head()
```

This will give you a `DataFrame` with all the original columns as well as the transformed columns.